# Tying composer.json to a specific Laravel 5 SHA

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I'm working on an experimental project using the as-yet unreleased Laravel 5. It seems that a recent commit effectively broke things, but rather than wait for the matter to be fixed I'd rather just continue using the development version I know to be working while monitoring the [commit log](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/develop). My current `composer.json` file looks like this (the relevant snippet):

```
  "name": "laravel/laravel",   
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "~5.0",    
    "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
  },
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
  "name": "laravel/laravel",   
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "~5.0#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c",    
    "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
  },
```

Per [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links) Composer supports the ability to bind to a specific SHA however when I run `composer update` I receive the message:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]                                 

Could not parse version constraint ~5.0#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c: 
Invalid version string "~5.0#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c"
```

Of course, I've tried various variants (`5.0#...`, `5#...`, etc) however all yield the same error message. Input appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sigh the answer hit me like a bolt of lightning. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/develop are obviously laravel/laravel commits, and *not* laravel/framework commits.

Even with my ridiculous oversight resolved, it remains unclear to me how one might go about locking to a particular version of laravel/laravel for the time being. There are workarounds to be certain, but I'm looking for the *right* way, if such a solution exists.

Sorry for the wheel spinning @Wouter and @Marcin, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the branch alias instead. You should use `5.0-dev#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c` as version:

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",   
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "5.0-dev#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c",    
  "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
},
```

Comment: Hmm no that doesn't work either. I've updated the relevant line to read `"laravel/framework": "5.0-dev#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c",` but receive the message `Could not parse version constraint 5.0-dev#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c: Invalid version string "5.0-dev#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c"`. I'm running the very latest version of Composer.

Comment: @Jason what if you try `dev-master#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c`?

Comment: Unfortunately I get "cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c is gone (history was rewritten?), recovered by checking out 49e3c77b518547bb661b1de4fda64a3ae0c5c505" when attempting this approach, same result as @marcin-nabiałek below. I x-posted over at Laracasts, perhaps they can shed some light on the problem. If so I'll definitely report back.

Comment: @Jason that means the commit was removed, you should try another commit then

Comment: Hi @Wouter I understand it means the commit was removed. But looking at [https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/develop](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/develop) indicates otherwise. The commit SHA is right there, and I can browse the code for that commit.

Comment: @Jason, that's the develop branch not the master branch. So you have to use `dev-develop# cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
"laravel/framework": "5.0.x-dev#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c",
```

instead of:

```
"laravel/framework": "~5.0#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c",
```

and install it using:

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

My exact `composer.json` file was:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",    
    "require": {
      "laravel/framework": "5.0.x-dev#cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c",
      "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

However you need to notice that during installation the following message is being displayed:

```
Installing laravel/framework (dev-master cd37f40)
    Cloning cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c
    cd37f40bba5dced6b1c30d313df2e46c5c33a62c is gone (history was rewritten?), recovered by checking out 5300b9eb19b5aeac8746835558419d274ee21621
```

so it seems this commit is not available but I'm not composer expert so I may be wrong.

**EDIT**

I've tried dozens of other settings but each time either it fails or it gets another commit and not the one you want.

Comment: OK fantastic. Going to give this a go this evening. I'm confused by the missing SHA though? See [https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/develop](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/develop), I'm specifically trying to attach to the commit identified by the message "Use helpers." because the "Simplify things" commit most definitely breaks things.

Comment: @Jason I've tried to solve it but I don't know why. I tried yesterday and today many settings but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Here's the similar question with an answer which helped me:

[composer | laravel 5 - Updating dependencies but the framework itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134943/composer-laravel-5-updating-dependencies-but-the-framework-itself)

```
"require": {
"laravel/framework": "dev-master#49e3c77b518547bb661b1de4fda64a3ae0c5c505",
...
}
```