# composer | laravel 5 - Updating dependencies but the framework itself

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-5

I am using pre-beta release of Laravel 5 for my project.

I found out that the app skeleton of Laravel 5 was changed in the github repo and since it is a development version, that is expected to change quite frequently.

My question is, can I update only the specific dependencies using composer and not the framework itself? So that I don't have to worry about the changing app structure until I am ready to make changes?

Here is how the composer.json dependencies look:

```
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "~5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "way/generators": "~3.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.5@dev"
    },
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could remove the "require"-part to make composer-updates of the dependencies possibly, but that is quite hacky and messy. But, it's possible. Not recommended in any way btw. Please note that JSON does not allow comments / commenting out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `composer update package package ...` answer is a good one, another thing you might be able to do is change your Laravel require spec to a specific commit. The [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links) mentions how to do this, and I've done it myself on a project (though not with laravel, on my own packages which are also in a breaking/dev state).

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "dev-master#49e3c77b518547bb661b1de4fda64a3ae0c5c505",
    ...
}
```

I'd hope that, because `laravel/framework` 'replaces' the various `illuminate/*` packages, that any reliance on these (as long as the spec is `5.0`-esque) that this would work without downloading the illuminate packages twice.

Doing it this way you can lock your `laravel/framework` (or any package) at a given commit, but still allow the standard `composer update` to work.

To find out what commit you're already on, if your `laravel/framework` dependency spec is a dev one then the `vendor/laravel/framework/` directory itself should be a git repo, so just do `git status` in there to get the HEAD ref. Alternatively, look in `composer.lock` for the `laravel/framework` entry's `source.reference` value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can simply call

```
composer update vendor/package
```

without updating your whole project.

It will work for the packages pulled by yourself and for the dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Composer allows you to do specific package upgrades. I used this literally the other night to upgrade a single package to fix a bug, but I didn't want to change anything else.

`composer update <package1> <package2> <...>`

So in your case

`composer update phpunit/phpunit way/generators fzaninotto/faker`

It might be more complicated when you have lots of packages - but it is a solution that works.

Answer (score -2):

You can't really. If you use Laravel 5 this is a thing you need to deal with, development versions come with this backdraw.